# How to use ingest pipelines on already indexed documents?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, kibana, foselasticabundle

I've been using FOSElasticaBundle to index my documents (which are entities from a Symfony project kept in a db through Doctrine) into Elastic Search. FOSElastica does an automatic mapping and index after that all the documents.

The problem is that there's some actions I would want to apply on every documents (on those already indexed and those which will be after), so pipelines and painless seems to be a good solution.

But, I can't get to understand how to apply a pipeline to documents that are already indexed, do you have an idea how ?

I've seen that you can add a "pipeline=my_pipeline_name" after an ES request but you can do it for a single document while I'd want it to affect all the documents.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.shubho.dev/devops/elastic-search-update-by-query-with-ingest-pipeline might be helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/pipeline.html) while you move your data from *one index* to *another index*.

You would need to make use of [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) in order for it to be executed on the data during its `movement/ingestion_process` from one index to another.

**Note:** This is *index level operation* meaning it would affect **all** the documents.

**Below is summary of steps:**

- Create a `temporary_index`,
- Reindex from `source_index` to `temporary_index` make use of [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html). Also including the pipeline (sample query provided below)
- Delete and re-create the `source_index`. Ensure that the mappings are also included while creating the index.
- Execute the same query this with `source_index` as destination name and `temporary_index` as source name ***without the pipeline***

Below is how you make use of Reindex API with pipeline

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source_index_name"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "temporary_index",
    "pipeline": "some_ingest_pipeline"
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: On an added note, if your index is too large and would want to see the status of reindex operations, while its still processing under the hood, refer to the `Task API`, which would help you give information as how many docs are processed and how many are still left during reindex operation. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-task-api

Comment: On recent Elasticsearch versions, the step 4 can be replaced by a `_clone` call : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clone-index.html

Answer (score 1):

So, after some time I found a way more efficient solution to my problems : [Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/dynamic-templates.html) and [Index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-templates.html)

I actually had trouble with ElasticSearch not recognizing some types of fields (like date or geo_point), so I forced them for specifically named fields with help of templates.

If you want an example of my configuration in FOSElastica ([doc is here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/templates.md)) :

```
fos_elastica:
    serializer: 
        serializer: jms_serializer
    clients:
        default: 
            host: localhost 
            port: 9200
    index_templates: # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-templates.html
        base_template: # this is a custom name for the index template
            client: default
            template: "*" # this is where you define which indices will use this template
            types:
                _doc: # this is where you define which types will use this (_doc stands for every type/documents)
                    dynamic_templates: # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/dynamic-templates.html
                        dynamic_date_template: # this is a custom name for the dynamic field template
                            match_pattern: regex
                            match: created|updated|tpq_date|taq_date
                            mapping:
                                type: date
                        dynamic_location_template:
                            match: location
                            mapping:
                                type: geo_point
```