# How split a field to words by ingest pipeline in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, split, pipeline, ingest

I have created an ingest pipeline as below to split a field into words:

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
    "pipeline": {
        "description": "String cutting processing",
        "processors": [
            {
                "split": {
                    "field": "foo",
                    "separator": "|"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "docs": [
        {
            "_source": {
                "foo": "apple|time"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but it split the field into characters:

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "foo" : [
            "a",
            "p",
            "p",
            "l",
            "e",
            "|",
            "t",
            "i",
            "m",
            "e"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I replace the separator with a comma, the same pipeline split the field to words:

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
    "pipeline": {
        "description": "String cutting processing",
        "processors": [
            {
                "split": {
                    "field": "foo",
                    "separator": ","
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "docs": [
        {
            "_source": {
                "foo": "apple,time"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

then the output would be:

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "foo" : [
            "apple",
            "time"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I split the field into words when the separator is "|"?
My next question is how could I apply this ingest pipeline to an existing index?
I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289749/how-to-use-ingest-pipelines-on-already-indexed-documents), but it doesn't work for me.

**Edit**

Here is the whole pipeline with the document that will assign two parts to two columns:

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "description": """combined fields are text that contain  "|" to separate two fields""",
    "processors": [
      {
        "split": {
          "field": "dv_m",
          "separator": "|",
          "target_field": "dv_m_splited"
        }
      },
      {
        "set": {
          "field": "dv_metric_prod",
          "value": "{{dv_m_splited.1}}",
          "override": false
        }
      },
      {
        "set": {
          "field": "dv_metric_section",
          "value": "{{dv_m_splited.2}}",
          "override": false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {

      "_source": {

        "dv_m": "amaze_inc|Understanding"

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That generates this response:

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "dv_metric_prod" : "m",
          "dv_m_splited" : [
            "a",
            "m",
            "a",
            "z",
            "e",
            "_",
            "i",
            "n",
            "c",
            "|",
            "U",
            "n",
            "d",
            "e",
            "r",
            "s",
            "t",
            "a",
            "n",
            "d",
            "i",
            "n",
            "g"
          ],
          "dv_metric_section" : "a",
          "dv_m" : "amaze_inc|Understanding"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2021-08-02T08:33:58.2234143Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I set `"separator": "\\|"`, then I will get this error:

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "error" : {
        "root_cause" : [
          {
            "type" : "general_script_exception",
            "reason" : "Error running com.github.mustachejava.codes.DefaultMustache@776f8239"
          }
        ],
        "type" : "general_script_exception",
        "reason" : "Error running com.github.mustachejava.codes.DefaultMustache@776f8239",
        "caused_by" : {
          "type" : "mustache_exception",
          "reason" : "Failed to get value for dv_m_splited.2 @[query-template:1]",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "mustache_exception",
            "reason" : "2 @[query-template:1]",
            "caused_by" : {
              "type" : "index_out_of_bounds_exception",
              "reason" : "2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: For the second issue (applying the pipeline to existing documents) I cannot think of anything else than re-indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is fairly simple: just escape your separator.

As the `separator` field in the **split** processor [is a regular expression](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/split-processor.html), you need to escape special characters such as `|`.

You also need to escape it twice.

So your code only lacks the double escaping part:

`POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate`

```json
{
    "pipeline": {
        "description": "String cutting processing",
        "processors": [
            {
                "split": {
                    "field": "foo",
                    "separator": "\\|"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "docs": [
        {
            "_source": {
                "foo": "apple|time"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

You did not mention or I missed the part where you wanted to assign the values to two separate fields.

In this case, you should use `dissect` instead of `split`. It is shorter, simpler, cleaner. See the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/dissect-processor.html).

`POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate`

```json
{
  "pipeline": {
    "description": """combined fields are text that contain  "|" to separate two fields""",
    "processors": [
      {
        "dissect": {
          "field": "dv_m",
          "pattern": "%{dv_metric_prod}|%{dv_metric_section}"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "dv_m": "amaze_inc|Understanding"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Result

```json
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "dv_metric_prod" : "amaze_inc",
          "dv_metric_section" : "Understanding",
          "dv_m" : "amaze_inc|Understanding"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2021-08-18T07:39:12.84910326Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**ADDENDUM**

> If using `split` instead of `dissect`

You got your array indices wrong. There is no such thing as `{{dv_m_splited.2}}` as the array index starts from 0 and you only have two results.

This is the correct pipeline when using the `split` processor.

`POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate`

```json
{
  "pipeline": {
    "description": """combined fields are text that contain  "|" to separate two fields""",
    "processors": [
      {
        "split": {
          "field": "dv_m",
          "separator": "\\|",
          "target_field": "dv_m_splited"
        }
      },
      {
        "set": {
          "field": "dv_metric_prod",
          "value": "{{dv_m_splited.0}}",
          "override": false
        }
      },
      {
        "set": {
          "field": "dv_metric_section",
          "value": "{{dv_m_splited.1}}",
          "override": false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "dv_m": "amaze_inc|Understanding"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works for this example, but it doesn't work when I apply it to the document. Any clue?

Comment: Please provide some sample document lines.

Comment: I put the whole pipeline with a sample document

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just got back from vacation. See the updated answer,

Comment: No problem. Actually, I could resolve it by dissect processors, but I was wondering could we do it with split?

Comment: Updated the answer with `split` instead of `dissect`